# При наведение на столбец появляется всплывающее окно с полным текстом ячейки столбца

Tags: html, css

У меня есть таблица, в ней слишком длинные названия в колонке, я обрезала названия теперь текст в столбце выглядит так «Аааааа...» 
При наведение на этот текст в столбце мне надо показывать полный текст «Аааааааааааааа».
Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
table td.t-Report-cell[headers=“names”]:hover::after
{
content:attr(innerText);
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:20%;tip:30%;
}
```

При этом он как будто не видит атрибут innerHtml
Буду благодарна, если подскажите, в чем ошибка/проблема

Comment: весь код приложите

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/behavior-nested-tooltip

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что дело в innerText. Укорачивание строки у вас скорее всего сделано через `overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis`. Значит псевдоэлемент `::after` не будет показываться за пределами ячейки таблицы. Но конечно без модельного кода трудно утверждать что-либо определенно.